# Matching any combination of space AND newline

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regexp that catches all instances that contain at least one `\n` and any number of  (space), no matter the order. So, for instance (with spaces denoted with `_`), all of these should be caught by the regexp:

```
\n
\n\n\n\n
\n\n\n_\n\n
_\n
\n_
_\n_
_\n\n
\n\n_
_\n\n_
_\n\n_\n
\n_\n_
_\n\n_\n_
___\n__\n and so on...
```

However, it must not catch spaces that do not border a `\n`.

In other words, I'd like to reduce all of this (if I'm not making any mistake) to one line:

```
import re
mystring = re.sub(r'(\n)+'  ,  '\n'  ,  mystring)
mystring = re.sub(r'( )+'   ,  ' '   ,  mystring)
mystring = re.sub(r'\n '    ,  '\n'  ,  mystring)
mystring = re.sub(r' \n'    ,  '\n'  ,  mystring)
mystring = re.sub(r'(\n)+'  ,  '\n'  ,  mystring)
mystring = re.sub(r'(\n)+'  ,  ' | ' ,  mystring)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `\s+`? Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve to avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: It looks like you want `_*\n_*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ ]*(?:\n[ ]*)+
```

or, if you want to match tabulations:

```
[ \t]*(?:\n[ \t]*)+
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7SSuPt/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(( )*\n+( )*)+
```